Is Async Call Applicable when there is a single rest call?
I am implementing a simple project in Python where I make one Rest call to fetch some JSON response, manipulate that response, and display the result.
Step 1: Make a Rest call, get a response
Step 2: Perform operations on the response
Step 3: Display the results
I am contemplating if I need to implement it as an Async call. Does it make sense design-wise?

For a single call, where you have to wait for the result, you don't get anything from async, so you can go with the simplest thing that could possibly work. That thing may be async, if libraries only support that.

@Robert Thank you Robert, so it does not make any sense to make it async right?
